# Sub program auto send results to main program (for LineBot on Heroku)

Tags: python-3.x, timer, task

Well~ briefly decribe

I'm working on LineBot  which set on Heroku

Main program is already done

And now working on it's function which may need sub program

1.
 My sub program use timer which runs every 20 seconds
Mainly use to detect newest earthquake info publish by government
and send to every user directly

I hope it can automatically send some result(time infomation) to my Main program in every 20 seconds (that's why I use Timer)
Is it possible?
(I can't use timer in Main program  once I run other function Timer may stop...)

2.If it's possible  how do I set or use my Sub program on Heroku?? (or maybe on other site which can help it auto run and send result to my Main program)

3.Can anyone teach me(or give me links) how to link two program together
ex:
A.py as Main
B.py as Sub

What should I do on B.py (ex:  the form of it's result)  so I can return results to A.py

Thanks a lot !!!

sub program code

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

def printTime(inc):
    dt = datetime.now()  
    m=dt.strftime('%m')
    d=dt.strftime('%d')
    H=dt.strftime('%H')
    M=dt.strftime('%M')
    print(m+d+H+M)
    t = Timer(inc, printTime, (inc,))
    t.start()

printTime(20)
```

Comment: Please post some code of what you already tried.